# Why would a single process in Google Chrome use over 2GB of RAM?

Tags: google-chrome, task-manager

I noticed that my Task Manager icon in the taskbar showed high resource usage, so I opened it to find that a single Chrome process was using over 2GB of RAM*. By closing Chrome tabs one at a time, I discovered [this site](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/) was the culprit. I hadn't even used it yet: I had only loaded the page. Why would this happen and should I be concerned?

[image: Screenshot showing website and Task manager]

*For you detail-oriented folks: the screenshot shows just over 1GB RAM being used because I closed the original tab and reopened it before taking the snap.

Comment: Well, several things might be happening, I think we could only guess - An advertisement, for instance, might be consuming the memory (there are some that loads heavy video content, for instance). When badly coded, an advertisement can have memory leaks and cause such problem.

Comment: @Sathya thanks for fixing that image. As you can tell from my 6 rep, I'm not well versed in posting yet.

Comment: Chrome has its own taskmanager . launch it and look if you see more details here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many reasons why a specific site may be using that much memory.

The site itself, being a PHP development sandbox, likely has quite a lot going on "under the hood", and so by itself will likely use more memory than a static site or basic content site.

As others have mentioned, ads could also be culprits.

If a specific plugin you're running interacts with this specific site, it could also be contributing.

The point is that there are many things that make up the modern web browser, and there are many things that make up the modern dynamic site, and each of these things could be contributors or culprits when you are tracking down what is causing a specific site to use more memory than others.

Chrome's Task Manager was included almost precisely because of these facts, allowing you to find tabs and sites that are using more than their share and close them.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I had never used the site before, so I was mainly concerned if that extra activity was malicious. It appears now it may just be "innocent", like a memory leak. I also learned that Chrome has a Task Manager. "The more you know...shooting star!"